expected a 512 bit key but a 256 bit key was provided
Getting this error on the authentication server when trying to use OIDC in a Jakarta EE 10 app.  I am guessing it must be one of the "extraParametersExpression" but I can't find that anywhere.
2024-10-12 03:06:47,199 WARN [org.util.function.FunctionUtils] - <Invalid key for dir with A256CBC-HS512, expected a 512 bit key but a 256 bit key was provided.
    JsonWebTokenEncryptor.java:encrypt:84
    BaseStringCipherExecutor.java:encryptValueAsJwt:185
    BaseStringCipherExecutor.java:lambda$encryptAndSign$6:294
    FunctionUtils.java:lambda$doIf$3:110

The error seems pretty obvious however I can't find a place to set the key length or algorithm in the OIDC annotation.
